# "List indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner at coding and I'm currently making an rpg. When I run the code, it gives me the above error. The part that is giving me the error is `print("You are on " + floors[currentRoom] + ". You find " + floorsFeature[currentRoom])`. My guess is that there must be something wrong with floors, floorsFeature, and currentRooms. Because I'm a beginner, I'm not sure what the error means. Can someone please explain in simple terms?

```
print("You are finally a Pokemon trainer! Today, you have gotten your very first Pokemon, a Bulbasaur!")
name = input("What will you name your Bulbasaur? ")
print("Unfortunately, " + name + " doesn't seem to obey or like you...")
print("You try to be friendly to " + name + ", but it just won't listen...")
print("As " + name + " was busy ignoring you, something seems to catch its attention and it runs off!")
print("You chase after " + name + ", but it's too fast! You see it running into an abandoned Pokeball Factory.")
print("You must explore the abandoned Pokeball Factory and find " + name + " before something happens to it!")
print()
print("You may input 'help' to display the commands.")
print()

gamePlay = True
floors = [['floor 1 room 1', 'floor 1 room 2', 'floor 1 room 3', 'floor 1 room 4'],['floor 2 room 1', 'floor 2 room 2', 'floor 2 room 3', 'floor 2 room 4', 'floor 2 room 5'],['floor 3 room 1,' 'floor 3 room 2', 'floor 3 room 3'],['floor 4 room 1', 'floor 4 room 2']]
floorsFeature = [['nothing here.', 'nothing here.', 'stairs going up.', 'a Squirtle.'],['stairs going up and a pokeball.', 'a Charmander.', 'a FIRE!!!', 'stairs going down.', 'a pokeball.'],['stairs going down.', 'a door covered in vines.', '2 pokeballs!'],['your Bulbasaur!!!', 'an Eevee with a key tied around its neck.']]
currentRoom = [0][1]
pokemonGot = []
count = 0
bagItems = []
countItems = 0

while gamePlay == True:
    print("You are on " + floors[currentRoom] + ". You find " + floorsFeature[currentRoom])
    move = input("What would you like to do? ")
    while foo(move) == False:
        move = input("There's a time and place for everything, but not now! What would you like to do? ")
    if move.lower() == 'left':
        if currentRoom > 0:
            currentRoom = currentRoom - 1
            print("Moved to " + floors[currentRoom] + ".")
        else:
            print("*Bumping noise* Looks like you can't go that way...")
    elif move.lower() == 'right':
        if currentRoom < len(floors) - 1:
            currentRoom = currentRoom + 1
            print("Moved to " + floors[currentRoom] + ".")
        else:
            print("*Bumping noise* Looks like you can't go that way...")
    elif move.lower() == 'help':
        print("Input 'right' to move right. Input 'left' to move left. Input 'pokemon' to see what Pokemon are on your team. Input 'bag' to see the items you are carrying. Input 'help' to see the commands again.")
    elif move.lower() == 'pokemon':
        if count == 0:
            print("There are no Pokemon on your team.")
        else:
            print("The Pokemon on your team are: " + ", ".join(pokemonGot) + ".")
    elif move.lower() == 'bag':
        if countItems == 0:
            print("There are no items in your bag.")
        else:
            print("The items in your bag are: " + ", ".join(bagItems) + ".")
    print()
```

Comment: currentRoom = [0][1]
is this piece of code correct? Just to double check

Comment: There is another typo error at `'floor 3 room 1,' 'floor 3 room 2', ...` The comma should be out of the quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to replicate your error with the code provided as it threw another error (list index out of range)

I suspect the issue is here

```
currentRoom = [0][1]
```

What this means is that you are trying to set the value of currentRoom to the index 1 of [0], which does not exist.

[0] here is a list containing one item.
If you are confused about this, fire up python3, and try this

```
currentRoom = [0,2][1]
print(currentRoom)
```

Based on your sample, you are using a nested list for your floor list.

floor[0] = floor 1, floor [0] = floor 2, etc.

within floor 1, you have another list, where each index determines your current room.

How about using two integers to hold the current position instead?

```
 currentRoom = 0 // room 1
 currentFloor = 0 //floor 1
 print (You are on floors[currentFloor][currentRoom], you find floorsFeature[currentFloor][currentRoom])
 ....
 ..... // user entered move left
 if currentRoom >0:
      currentRoom -= 1
      print (Moved to floors[currentFloor][currentRoom])
 .... //user went up by one floor
 if ....
      currentFloor += 1
      print (Moved to floors[currentFloor][currentRoom])
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets go by parts:

## Provide all the needed code:

We do not know what the `foo()` function does. It seems to be a validating function but we are missing that part of the code. Please always provide a piece of code we can run to check your errors.

## `foo()` replacement:

To check a choice against a valid set of options you can do it in a single line:

```
1 in [1, 2, 3] # Output: True
4 in {1, 2, 3} # Output: False
4 not in {1, 2, 3} # Output: True
"b" in ("a", "b", "c") # Output: True
"abc" in ("a", "b", "c") # Output: False
"a" in "abc" # Output: True
```

As you can see I've used different values (`int` and `str`) and different containers (`list`, `set`, `tuple`, `str`, ...) and I could use even more. Using `not in` gives you the opposite answer as expected. In your case you could use:

```
commands = {'help', 'pokemons', 'bag', 'left', 'right'}
while move not in commands:
    ...
```

## String formating:

There are multiple ways of formatting strings to include variables values inside them, but the most pythonic way is using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). You can check the documentation on how the formatting string works [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatstrings), but the most simple example would be:

```
print("Unfortunately, {} doesn't seem to obey or like you...".format(name))
```

Basically you use placehodlers delimited by `{}` and then call the `.format()` function with the arguments you want to place there. Inside the `{}` you can place different additional strings to format the output as for example determining the number of decimals of a float number.

## `list`s and `tuple`s:

Both `list`s and `tuple`s in Python are sequence containers. The main difference in that the `list` is mutable and the `tuple` isn't. They are both accessed with the `var[position]` notation starting from `0`. So if you are not going to ever change the content of a sequence, you should use a `tuple` instead of a list to enforce it to the interpreter and to be more memory efficient. You use parenthesis instead of square brackets for tuples.

## `dict`s

`dict`s are a great way of holding state:

```
player = {
          'floor': 1,
          'room': 2,
          'pokemons': [],
          'bag': [],
         }
```

## You don't have to store the length of an array:

In some languages you always keep the ammount of items inside an array stored. Python's containers can determine at runtime their size by calling `len(container)`. You have used it at some parts of the code but you are keeping a `count` and `countItems` variables that are not needed.

## Multi dimensional lists (a.k.a. matrixes):

You seem to be having some problems dealing with matrixes, use the following notation: `matrix[i][j]` to access the `j+1`th element (as it starts in 0) of the `i+1`th list.

```
matrix = [
          [1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9],
         ]
print(matrix[1][2]) # Output: 6
```

To know the number of lists, in your case floors, use `len(matrix)`. To know the number of elements of the n-th list use `len(matrix[n-1])`.

## The final code:

```
commands = {'help', 'pokemons', 'bag', 'left', 'right', 'exit'}

gamePlay = True
features = (
            ['nothing here.'                  , 'nothing here.'                            , 'stairs going up.', 'a Squirtle.'       ],
            ['stairs going up and a pokeball.', 'a Charmander.'                            , 'a FIRE!!!'       , 'stairs going down.', 'a pokeball.'],
            ['stairs going down.'             , 'a door covered in vines.'                 , '2 pokeballs!'],
            ['your Bulbasaur!!!'              , 'an Eevee with a key tied around its neck.'],
           )

player = {
          'floor': 1,
          'room': 2,
          'pokemons': [],
          'bag': [],
         }

def positionString(player):
    return "floor {p[floor]} room {p[room]}".format(p=player)

def featureString(player):
    return features[player['floor']-1][player['room']-1]

print("You are finally a Pokemon trainer! Today, you have gotten your very first Pokemon, a Bulbasaur!")
name = input("What will you name your Bulbasaur? ")
print("Unfortunately, {} doesn't seem to obey or like you...".format(name))
print("You try to be friendly to {}, but it just won't listen...".format(name))
print("As {} was busy ignoring you, something seems to catch its attention and it runs off!".format(name))
print("You chase after {}, but it's too fast! You see it running into an abandoned Pokeball Factory.".format(name))
print("You must explore the abandoned Pokeball Factory and find {} before something happens to it!".format(name))
print()
print("You may input 'help' to display the commands.")
print()

while gamePlay == True:
    print("You are on {}. You find {}".format(positionString(player), featureString(player)))
    move = input("What would you like to do? ").lower()
    while move not in commands:
        move = input("There's a time and place for everything, but not now! What would you like to do? ").lower()
    if move == 'left':
        if player['room'] > 1:
            player['room'] -= 1
            print("Moved to {}.".format(positionString(player)))
        else:
            print("*Bumping noise* Looks like you can't go that way...")
    elif move == 'right':
        if player['room'] < len(features[player['floor']-1]):
            player['room'] += 1
            print("Moved to {}.".format(positionString(player)))
        else:
            print("*Bumping noise* Looks like you can't go that way...")
    elif move == 'help':
        print("Input 'right' to move right. Input 'left' to move left. Input 'pokemons' to see what Pokemon are on your team. Input 'bag' to see the items you are carrying. Input 'help' to see the commands again.")
    elif move == 'pokemons':
        if len(player['pokemons']) == 0:
            print("There are no Pokemon on your team.")
        else:
            print("The Pokemon on your team are: {}.".format(", ".join(player['pokemons'])))
    elif move == 'bag':
        if len(player['bag']) == 0:
            print("There are no items in your bag.")
        else:
            print("The items in your bag are: {}.".format(", ".join(player['bag'])))
    elif move == 'exit':
        gamePlay = False
    print()
```

As you can see I've made two functions to get the name of the room and the feature of the room from the state vector so that I do not have to duplicate that part of the code anywhere. One of the function is generating the string itself as they all had the same scheme: `floor X room Y`. Holding them on a matrix makes no sense unless you wnat to give them names such as `'lobby'`, I let you the task of modifying the function if thats the case, it should be easy as it would be very similar to the second one. I've also added an 'exit' command to get out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define `currentRoom = [0][1]`:

```
>>> currentRoom = [0][1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

`[0][1]` is not an integer, a string or another type. You can use a list or a tuple to keep floor and room info:

```
#To get floor 3, room 2
currentRoom = [2,1] # Or you can use currentRoom = (2,1)
print(floors[currentRoom[0]][currentRoom[1]]) # It refers print(floors[2][1])
```

Output:

```
floor 3 room 2
```

---

The error in the header can occur when you do:

```
>>> currentRoom = (2,1)
>>> print(floors[currentRoom])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Use the solution above:

```
print(floors[currentRoom[0]][currentRoom[1]])
```